# What are the differences between the PS2 and PS3 versions of Fifa 12?

Tags: fifa-12

I've done a silly thing. Finally got a PS3 to play some next gen games and shopped online for Fifa 12. Turns out I bought the PS2 version--I didn't even know they were still making games for the thing!

I haven't taken the plastic wrapping off yet so I still have a couple of days to return it. Is it worth it trade up to the PS3 version? What are its advantages over the PS2 copy? I don't care much about graphics quality; only gameplay. Most importantly, can I play the PS2 version on my PS3 and will it support more than two players?

Comment: Note that the latest PS3 models don't have any kind of PS2 compatibility, so that alone may be a show-stopper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this point, games released for the PS2 are so far down a publisher's/developer's priority list that they might as well not exist.  People have reported [framerate issues and gameplay problems](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/631379-fifa-soccer-12/60742768), although others were happy with everything [except the graphics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004Z4ZJMQ), which you note aren't that important to you.

I can't find a side-by-side review, or a review of the multiplayer support, (or even a professional review of the PS2 version, period!) so I can't answer that part of your question directly.  However, the [publisher's site](http://www.ea.com/soccer/fifa/ps2) lists 3 features on the PS2 version versus 12 for the PS3 version, so it's safe to assume that the PS2 version is relatively stripped down compared to the PS3 version.

Since you paid money to upgrade to the Playstation 3, and you're paying money to play the latest iteration of the franchise, why not spend a few dollars more on the game to make sure you get the best experience possible?

Comment: Thanks both. You're right, I should get an actual PS3 version. I won't return the other though; instead I'll bestow it on a PS3-less friend for Christmas =)

Comment: Iiiiits the mooooost wonderful tiiiiime ooooof the yeeeear!

Answer (score 2):

The pages on the EA Sports website for the [PS2 version](http://www.ea.com/uk/football/fifa/ps2) and the [PS3 version](http://www.ea.com/uk/football/fifa/ps3) are instructive, with the PS2 version listing 3 features while the PS3 version has 12.

The PS2 version page does not mention online at all so you would be missing out on features like:

- Head to Head Season - play matches against online opponents, with everyone separated into divisions based on results (handled by a promotion and relegation system), so you'll generally be playing against opponents of your own skill.
- Ultimate Team  - a card-collecting game where you use the cards to get better players and for power-ups during matches.
- Challenges - You are presented with a real-life game scenario where you have to try to match or better the actual result.
- Virtual Pro Clubs - Play as your Virtual Pro with and against other players using their Virtual Pro.

Assuming your PS3 is online, I think it would be worth getting the PS3 version just for Head to Head Season alone - it's much more satisfying to play against a human rather than the AI, and the matchmaking works really well so you don't have to worry about getting flogged all the time.